# Cent OS 7.3 failed to create php-fpm.sock

Tags: php, mysql, nginx, fpm

I am trying to install mysql+ nginx +php+php-fpm in a centOS 7.3 server
I am following

https://sg.godaddy.com/help/build-a-lemp-stack-linux-nginx-mysql-php-centos-7-17349

it failed to create /run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock

Could you please help me to fix it?

Comment: sorry for it, I will delete it

Comment: where can I ask this question?

Comment: well, I don't know for now, but as it's not about programming it should not be on stackoverflow